# Can multiple characters have the same familiar using the Find Familiar spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

Is there anything RAW that would prevent two different characters using the Find Familiar spell from intentionally gaining the service of the same familiar spirit?

I am aware that if 1 familiar was 'contracted' to two different casters, it would create some interesting circumstances and limitations, but I'm currently concerned with whether it's possible, not how it works. As a DM, I hope to introduce a pair of NPCs where this is the case, but I'm mostly just curious, if this situation is possible within the conventional rules.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the rules strictly preventing it. So it isn't impossible.  However if one has it out, and the other casts the spell, a different spirit would logically have to appear.  Because [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) says one shows up:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that takes an animal form you choose: bat, cat, crab, frog (toad), hawk, lizard, octopus, owl, poisonous snake, fish (quipper), rat, raven, sea horse, spider, or weasel. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.

It also says that it stays where you tell it to go until it is unsummoned or put in its pocket dimension:

> As an action, you can temporarily dismiss your familiar. It disappears into a pocket dimension where it awaits your summons. Alternatively, you can dismiss it forever. As an action while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause it to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you.

Thus, if one is summoned and obeys the first caster's commands, staying where the first one leaves it, the same familiar can't also be summoned by the second caster simultaneously.  For NPCs, this shouldn't be a problem because they are both under your control.  PCs shouldn't hope to try to share a familiar.

Also, note that NPCs also have access to the Familiar Variants that PC don't have access to.  Though those don't use the *find familiar* spell.

Comment: Yeah NPC magic is worth highlighting, NPC's are not limited to just what players can do.

Comment: The fist quote does not support your statement before it. The familiar could teleport as a result of the second casting, thus "appearing". In your second quote you did not include the part where it says that your familiar obeys you. Also, a summoning by a second caster could be considered a forceful effect, and nowhere does it say that the spirit has to be willing, so its obeisance to a master might not matter.